# Material Theme resource not found

Tags: android, gradle, android-appcompat, android-build, build-tools

i have a project and everything worked until i added `Mikepenz Material Drawer` library. it seems to use the Material Themes which should be present but are not.

Error message while building gradle: `Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'MaterialTheme'` (and all other material themes)

build.gradle file for :app

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ir.yooneskh.booktemplate"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

(it's a piece of it)

Build tools installed:

[image]

What am i missing?

Comment: add this to your dependency compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'

Comment: How did you add the Mikepenz Material Drawer library. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to add following libraries to resolve MaterialTheme error

```
implementation('com.mikepenz:materialize:0.8.5@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.5.8@aar'
implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.4.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1' 
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
}
```

**Instead of:**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Comment: Hmmm i get the failed to resolve error. what repo are they in?